# React updating array dynamically and passing it to child component

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-router

I have array in parent component that I need to update dynamically after reading some JSON from api.
I'm using react router and I'm able to pass the array to child component and add a css class based on the array values but I can't seem to figure out how to properly update my array and change array value of panelone to off.

Parent component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, NavLink, HashRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Child from './components/Child';

class App extends Component {

  arr = {
    panelone : 'on',
    paneltwo: 'off'
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    // Some function to get JSON... 
      this.arr.panelone = 'off'; // ???
    //...
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <TopBar />
        <HashRouter>
          <div>
            <nav>
              <ul className="header">
                <li><NavLink exact to="/">Overview</NavLink></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
            <div className="main-container">
              <Route 
                exact path="/" 
                render={(props) => <Child arr = {this.arr} />} 
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </HashRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Child component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

class Child extends Component {

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
      //This is working OK and css class "on" is added from panelone val
                <div className={'item ' + this.props.arr.panelone}>
                  <p>Some Title</p>
                </div>
            </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Child;
```

What is the proper way to update arr dynamically and update child components while using react router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use state for that, then call `setState()` to update. Have you read this: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class ?

You cannot set or update props directly. I would do something like this:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      arr = {
        panelone : 'on',
        paneltwo: 'off'
      }
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      arr: {
        ...this.state.arr,
        panelone: 'off'
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Actually, I did read it, but I can't seem to make it work with react router

Comment: If you use state instead of props it will rerender itself and all children when you call setState. Try changing this line: `render={(props) => <Child arr = {this.arr} />}` to this: `render={() => <Child arr = {this.state.arr} />}` as well.

Comment: Got it, Thank You!

Comment: Great! Glad to hear it

Answer (score 1):

That `arr` is actually a instance field object, so the right way to access it and update it is through `this` keyword:

```
componentDidMount() {
  // Some function to get JSON... 

  this.arr = {panelone: 'off', paneltwo: 'on'}

  //...
}
```

But that would leave you with the problem that React doesnt update child components when you update custom instance fields.

So the right way will be using the component's state. At the beginning `App`'s class define the state with `arr` inside:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    arr: {
      panelone: 'off', paneltwo: 'on'
    }
  };
}
```

Then instead of updating `arr` as an instance field you should use `setState` method:

```
componentDidMount() {
  // Some function to get JSON... 

  this.setState({
    arr: {
      panelone: 'off', 
      paneltwo: 'on'
    }
  });

  //...
}
```

In the render method of `App` use `this.state.arr` instead of `this.arr`:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <TopBar />
        <HashRouter>
          <div>
            <nav>
              <ul className="header">
                <li><NavLink exact to="/">Overview</NavLink></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
            <div className="main-container">
              <Route 
                exact path="/" 
                render={(props) => <Child arr = {this.state.arr} />} 
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </HashRouter>
      </div>
    );
}
```

And it will just work the way you are currently doing with the `Child` component, you should check [state documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class)

Comment: Thanks. If I use constructor on main component I'm getting: TypeError: Cannot read property 'panelone' of undefined.  from Child component line: this.props.arr.panelone

Comment: Check @pigeontoe reply to his answer

Comment: Got it. Many Thanks